# How can I remove the blank item in SharePoint Admin API access (webApiPermissionManagement)?

Tags: spfx, azure-ad, sharepoint-app-registration

Within the SharePoint admin center for API Access I have an approved request, but its blank (Highlighted line).
https://[tenant]-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/webApiPermissionManagement

[image: Empty Approved Request]
Unfortunately, I'm unable to remove access. I just get an error message saying `We couldn't remove access. Try again.`

I know this is tied to the App Registration/Enterprise Application "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal". As I can see my expected permission showing.

[image]

However, when I view the Enterprise permissions, it's unable to load the screen.

[image: Enterprise API]

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Happy to use PNP, M365 Cli, REST API etc to correct my environment.

Comment: That looks like a bug. I suggest you report it here https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues

Comment: Thanks @RobWindsor. I've just raised a service support call with Microsoft too. I have a feeling its a problem with my tenant more than an issue with spfx.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up raising this as an issue on GitHub as suggested by Rob Windsor.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/7843

The answer is:

- Find App Registration "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal" in Azure AD and delete it
- Ensure you remove it from Deleted Application Registrations too.
- Navigate back to the API Access Page in SharePoint. This will re-trigger application principal provisioning. It can take a while before it shows in AAD again. (I gave it 5 minutes or so)

***Note that you will have to re-approve the permissions by going to the App catalog and re-reploy your package***

Once I had performed the above, I no longer had the empty entry, and all screens loaded correctly.